# Saving 16-bit image in opencv with cmap (cv::ColorMap only supports source images of type CV_8UC1 or CV_8UC3 in function 'operator()')

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

I'm trying to save/show a 16-bit numpy array (as image) in opencv with cmap, it doesn't work. On the other hand, it works smoothly in matplotlib.

My deep learning model gives a numpy array `arr` (`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`). You can get it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p83yohb2m4o7wgy/pred_depth_scale.npy?dl=0).

```
# np array predicted from a depth model
>>> arr16 = np.load('pred_depth_scale.npy')
>>> arr16.dtype, arr16.shape
(dtype('uint16'), (466, 492))
>>> cv2.imshow('img', arr16)
# shows image in grayscale
```

[image: uint16_cv2_imshow]

I want to convert it to other colormap:

```
>>> arr16 = cv2.applyColorMap(arr16, cv2.COLORMAP_COOL)
```

It throws the following error:

> error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/colormap.cpp:684:
>   error: (-5:Bad argument) cv::ColorMap only supports source images of
>   type CV_8UC1 or CV_8UC3 in function 'operator()'

Now, if I convert the image to `uint8`, the image contains noise.

```
>>> arr8 = arr16.astype(np.uint8)
>>> arr8 = cv2.applyColorMap(arr8, cv2.COLORMAP_COOL)
>>> cv2.imshow('img', arr8)
```

[image: uint8_cv2_imshow]

On the other hand, with matplotlib, `cmap` works fine as follows:

```
>>> plt.imshow(arr16, cmap='magma')
```

[image: uint16_plt_imshow]

My **question** is: How do I save/show a 16-bit image in opencv with cmap?

Comment: Instead of `arr8 = arr16.astype(np.uint8)`, use `arr8 = (arr16/256).astype(np.uint8)`. You need to properly scale your image from `[0 ... 65535]` to `[0 ... 255]`. Applying the colormap, and showing and saving (**as 8-bit images!**) then also works in OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks @HansHirse, it works. Is there any way I can save 16-bit images with cmap as well?

Comment: Not solely using OpenCV, I'm afraid. You'll need to write your own conversion 16-bit grayscale --> 16-bit RGB with colormap. (That's not that difficult, but you have to code it yourself.)

Comment: The noise is due to the direct conversion from float to 8bit. you should rescale first and then apply conversion.

Answer (score 5):

The noise in the 8-bit image while plotting was due to improper scaling. It can be scaled from 16-bit (`[0 ... 65535]` to 8-bit `[0 ... 255]`) by the following *(thanks to @HansHirse in the comments)*:

```
arr8 = (arr16/256).astype(np.uint8).
```

`matplotlib` internally converts the image to 32 bit float internally before displaying it, and the colormaps are limited to 8-bits (as per the [github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16315)):

> We internally convert to 32bit floats in the normalization pipeline, then apply the colormap palettes which are typically limited to 255 values, but you can create your own palettes with more values.